# Notation of set on $R^2$ (attractor of Cantor dust)

Tags: geometry, fractals

I am studying fractal geometry, and pretty much confused by the notation/meaning below:

Quote:
The Cantor dust is easily seen to be the attractor of the four similarities on $R^2$ which give the basic self-similarities of the set:

$S_1(x,y)=(x/4,y/4+1/2)$, $S_2(x,y)=(x/4+1/4,y/4)$,

$S_3(x,y)=(x/4+1/2,y/4+3/4)$, $S_4(x,y)=(x/4+3/4,y/4+1/4)$

Question:
What do these set notations mean? Can x,y be any value as wish? How is this an attractor of Cantor?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: It means the set is the invariant set of the [IFS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system) consisting of those four functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it, after nearly trying to put my head against wall. :)

It turns out to be simple.

The Cantor dust definition gives $x \in [0,1], y \in [0,1]$

Hence:

$S_1(x,y)=([0,1/4],[1/2,3/4])$

$S_2(x,y)=([1/4,1/2],[0,1/4])$

$S_3(x,y)=([1/2,3/4],[3/4,1])$

$S_4(x,y)=([3/4,1],[1/4,3/4])$

Union of these sets defines exactly the attractor of Cantor dust.

Comment: This doesn't look quite right. Each $S_i$ is a *function* mapping $\mathbb R^2$ to itself. You've described each $S_i$ as an ordered pair of intervals. I would guess that you mean for each ordered pair of intervals to be a Cartesian product, defining a square in the plane, and mean to say that each $S_i$ maps the unit square onto the corresponding square. For example, the image of the unit square under the function $S_1$ is exactly $[0,1]\times[1/2,3/4]$. This Cantor dust is then the limit of repeated application of the IFS.

Comment: Mark, yes, that what I mean. But at the same time, I am a bit confused on how to define a triangle in the plane and map the serpinski triangle to it. My tutor said the $S_i$ similarities are (1/3x,1/3y), (1/3x+1/3,1/3y),(1/3x+2/3,1/3y)... i=1..6. However, these pair of intervals seem to have defined the image of squares only. Any lights? :)